# Reactive Forms - how to only get the values that are currently in the view?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In the template-driven approach, I could have:

```
<form #templateDrivenForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(templateDrivenForm.value)>
  <input name="input1" ngModel="value1" /> 
  <input *ngIf="false" name="input2" ngModel="value2"/> 
</form
```

and it would only pass in the `{ input1: "value1" }` as that's the only input that the form has in the template.

How to accomplish the same in the reactive approach?

If I have:

```
var reactiveForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  input1: ['value1'],
  input2: ['value2']
})
```

I would need an easy way to get `{ input1: "value1" }` if the `input2` has an `*ngIf="false"` on it.

I'm hoping that I don't have to manually strip out these values right before passing it to the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as stated in [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#value)

> For an enabled FormGroup, the values of enabled controls as an object with a key-value pair for each member of the group.

we can utilize this feature to implement your use case. when you hide your input with ngIf, simultaneously you can disable the formControl that input is associated with. thus while you submit the form FormGroup.value will return values for only enabled controls which are the visible ones.

here is a simple demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uivptc

Comment: I will change that input2 to `<input [hidden]="reactiveForm.get('input2').disabled [disabled]="someLongCondition">` and it will work perfectly. Thank you!